# I have a requirement to configure 2 LDAP servers which are 2 different domains in websphere appliocation server

Tags: ldap, websphere

I have a requirement to configure or federate 2 LDAP's in BAW/Was environment. They belong to 2 different domains like mof.com and mon.com with same port no 389, Is this possible, so how we can do it from was point of view or BAW configuration manager

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate multiple LDAPs via Federated repository. There are some limitations e.g. it is required that the user ID, and the distinguished name (DN) for an LDAP repositories, be unique in multiple user repositories that are configured under the same federated repository. Check these pages for more details:

- [Federate repositories](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=configuration-federated-repositories)
- [Configuring multiple LDAPs in a federated repository configuration](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=mrifrc-configuring-multiple-ldap-repositories-in-federated-repository-configuration)